# Generic TWAIN driver for OS x?

Tags: scanning, macos

I am looking for a generic TWAIN driver for OS X, one that would not need additional hardware. I just want to use it for testing TWAIN.

Comment: All I need is to install a driver that will enable me to open its window from an TWAIN enabled application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by installing the demo version of [VueScan](http://www.hamrick.com/). If someone else find a free tool that installs a driver that is visible in Photoshop, I will accept his answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In  OS X TWAIN is not "The Scanner Standard" as in windows. For OS X  several scanner manufacturers make TWAIN drivers and some others make plugins into various applications and *not* TWAIN, so IMHO you cannot rely (only) on TWAIN.

For the testing/developent TWAIN/SANE may help you - check this link:

http://www.ellert.se/twain-sane/

Access scanners via *SANE* - and enable the TWAIN datasource.